How to securely run HashiCorp Vault with mTLS with certificates that are not in the vault?
I want to run HashiCorp Vault with mTLS. I use Docker compose for this:
version: "3"
services:

  vault:
    image: hashicorp/vault:latest
    container_name: vault
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8200:8200"
    environment:
      VAULT_ADDR: "https://vault:8200"
      VAULT_API_ADDR: "https://vault:8200"
    command: server
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - ./config.hcl:/vault/config/config.hcl
      - ./certs/vault.crt:/certs/vault.crt
      - ./certs/vault.key:/certs/vault.key
      - ./certs/ca.pem:/certs/ca.pem

this is the config.hcl:
storage "file" {
  path    = "/vault/data"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address     = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = "false"
  tls_cert_file = "/certs/vault.crt"
  tls_key_file = "/certs/vault.key"
  tls_client_ca_file = "/certs/ca.pem"
  tls_require_and_verify_client_cert = "true"
}

ui = true
disable_mlock = true

As you can see, I need to mount files, especially vault.key, which must be on the disk. Which goes against the idea of having secrets in vault. Sure, I have all the other secrets in vault, but not the ones to mount the vault itself.
How can I secure vault secrets?

I feel like your question isn't really about Vault. If people have root permissions to read files your Vault filesystem, you'll likely have bigger security issues. The solution includes restricting physical/network access to that machine

@OneCricketeer This is most probably true, but maybe Vault itself has some way, which I missed while reading the tutorials, to handle the security of its own certificates.

Maybe, but how are you storing the unseal keys? Also on some disks?

@OneCricketeer Actually this is not decided yet, but I assume these will be stored somewhere. But I think I get your point, storing unseal keys is also important - we don't want user to type them from a piece of paper everytime the application is run. These needs to be stored somewhere as well.
